# joinWith multiple tables yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Hi is possible to join multiple table based on a column in yii 2? Right now I am using the concept of `joinWith`

Take a look at my code:

ActiveCurriculum.php
This is where I am joining the tables

```
 public static function Addblock($group, $clientid){
    $subjects =  ActiveCurriculum::find()
    ->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*', 'glhead.*', 'glfees.*'])
    ->joinWith('schead')
    ->joinWith('glhead')
    ->joinWith('glfees')
    ->where([
      'scstock.sectiongroup' => $group
      ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
}
```

And these are the relations that I set:

Scstock

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Scstock extends ActiveRecord{
  public static function tableName()
  {
      return '{{%scstock}}';
  }

  public function getSchead(){
     return $this->hasOne(Schead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getGlhead(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glhead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getGlfees(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glfees::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }


  }?>
```

Schead

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Schead extends ActiveRecord{
  public static function tableName()
  {
      return '{{%schead}}';
  }

  public function getScstock(){
     return $this->hasOne(ActiveCurriculum::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getGlhead(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glhead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getGlfees(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glfees::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  }?>
```

Glhead

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Glhead extends ActiveRecord{
  public static function tableName()
  {
      return '{{%glhead}}';
  }


  public function getScstock(){
     return $this->hasOne(ActiveCurriculum::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getSchead(){
     return $this->hasOne(Schead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getGlfees(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glfees::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  }?>
```

Glfees

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class Glfees extends ActiveRecord{
  public static function tableName()
  {
      return '{{%glfees}}';
  }

  public function getGlhead(){
    return $this->hasOne(Glhead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }

  public function getSchead(){
     return $this->hasOne(Schead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }


  public function getScstock(){
     return $this->hasOne(ActiveCurriculum::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
  }




  }?>
```

But I am getting this error when the query executes

[image]

```
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

app\models\ActiveCurriculum has no relation named "glhead".
↵
Caused by: Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException

Calling unknown method: app\models\ActiveCurriculum::getglhead()

in C:\xampp\htdocs\enrollment\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php at line 285
```

Am I doing something wrong with the relations or is it something else? Help would be greatly appreaciated. Thank you.

Comment: `ActiveCurriculum` class?

Comment: yes, in the php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these relations:

```php
->joinWith('schead')
->joinWith('glhead')
->joinWith('glfees')
```

must be declared in `ActiveCurriculum` class. Consult [relations in Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).